# Create CSS Grid with for each loop

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid, svelte, svelte-component

So I found part of this code online and I am stuck the past couple hours on this simple problem. I am trying to add a property *grid-row* and *grid-column* to the cell class, because I want to add a DIV which overlaps all the cells.

This is the behavior I am currently getting:
https://svelte.dev/repl/4888e5b498a442298ca8862a68b55ee6?version=3.49.0

This is the expected working end result, but here the properties *gird-row* and *grid-column* are missing in the cell class:
https://svelte.dev/repl/8da356605a36450187cbcbcdaf4a6188?version=3.49.0

Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: Please add the relevant code/screenshots to the question. REPLs are a nice optional thing, but the question should be self-contained (i.e. not depend on external links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` indexes are 0-based, grid properties are 1-based, so you probably need:

```
style="grid-row: {i + 1}; grid-column: {j + 1};"
```

Or with style directives:

```
style:grid-row={i + 1}
style:grid-column={j + 1}
```